# Showing advanced custom field as hyperlink

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, printf

I'm newbie to PHP and cannot figure out a simple thing:

I need to output the "advanced custom field" on Woordpress as a hyperlink.
Below is the code I am using but I am not sure how to properly make the **the_field('my-custom-link')**
to become a hyperlink. It's currently showing the output but it's not showing it as a wrapped link like I would like to.

```
printf( '<div class="pdf-cover"><a href="' . the_field('my-custom-link') .'" title="%s">%s</a></div>', the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ), $img );
```

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any function `the_field` on Wordpress, so it means you're using a plugin.

However, most wordpress and wp related functions have an echoing version (in this case `the_field`) and a returning version (which should be `get_the_field` or `get_field`)

So, please try

```
printf( '<div class="pdf-cover"><a href="' . get_the_field('my-custom-link') .'" title="%s">%s</a></div>', the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ), $img );
```

or

```
printf( '<div class="pdf-cover"><a href="' . get_field('my-custom-link') .'" title="%s">%s</a></div>', the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ), $img );
```